# JQuery: how to removeClass on click outside of element?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

This script runs my drop-down menu by toggling the .open and .close classes on click. How can I close this drop-down menu when the user clicks outside of the menu?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("li").addClass("closed");
        $("li.sel").on("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            });
        $("#navi1 li").click(function(){
            $("#navi1 li").toggleClass("open");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$("yourNavMenu").blur(function(){
   // Add your close class
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('*').not('#navi li').click(function(){
    $('#navi li').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Essentially, you need to call a function on any click event, and, for every menu, if the event does not occur within that menu *or one of the menu's child elements*, then the menu's close function is called. Of course, your close function will edit the class attribute instead of using the jQuery fade functions. As you can see, I have several menus called "subscribe", "about me", "about this website", etc. I hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // menu hide/show logic
    var TOGGLE_SPEED = 100;

    var subscribe_menu = $("#subscribe-container");
    var about_me = $("#about-me-container");
    var about_this_website = $("#about-this-website-container");
    var filter_menu = $("#filter-menu-container");
    var img_menu = $("#img-menu-container");

    var menuList = [subscribe_menu, about_me, about_this_website, filter_menu, img_menu];

    function hideMenu(menu){
        menu.fadeOut(TOGGLE_SPEED);
    }

    function showMenu(menu){
        menu.fadeIn(TOGGLE_SPEED);
    }

    function toggleMenu(menu){
        menu.fadeToggle(TOGGLE_SPEED);
    }

    function hideOthers(e){
         for (var i in menuList) {
            var menu = menuList[i];
            // check to see if the event target is the menu
            // or one of its children
            if (!menu.is(e.target) && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) { hideMenu(menu); }
        };
    }

    function clickHandler(menu){
        var e = $.Event("click");
        e.target = menu;
        hideOthers(e);
        toggleMenu(menu);
    }

    $(document).click(function(e){
        hideOthers(e);
    });

    $("#subscribe-tab").click(function(){
        clickHandler(subscribe_menu);
        return false;
    });

    $("#about-me-tab").click(function(){
        clickHandler(about_me);
        return false;
    });

    $("#about-this-website-tab").click(function(){
        clickHandler(about_this_website);
        return false;
    });

    $("#filter-tab").click(function(){
        clickHandler(filter_menu);
        return false;
    });

    $("#img-menu-button").click(function(){
        clickHandler(img_menu);
        return false;
    });

});
```